# Ripple JSON API - Can I use more than one destination while transaction?

Tags: ripple, ripple-gateways, ripple-api, ripple-client, ripple-trust

In Ripple API,

Is there any apis available to split payment which I can pass more than one destination address in single transaction.

Let me share code:

```
const RippleAPI = require('ripple-lib').RippleAPI;

const api = new RippleAPI({
    server: 'wss://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51233' // Public rippled server
});



//Payment API:
const address = 'r4Ct32uDZvL9e5GRbPftAnu8rpCg7aXXXX';
const secret = 'shvtBfNDJ3yf9sqGoc7XUgSTnXXXX';
const instructions = {maxLedgerVersionOffset: 5};
const payment = {
    source: {
        address: address,
        maxAmount: {
            value: '1.01',
            currency: 'XRP'
        }
    },
    destination: [{
        address: 'rn8KqzsH7b8fGZYmbaDXinLb8XffneXXXX',
        amount: {
            value: '1.01',
            currency: 'XRP'
        }
    },
    {
        address: 'rn8KqzsH7b8fGZYmbaDXinLb8XffneXXXX',
        amount: {
            value: '2.01',
            currency: 'XRP'
        }
    }]
};
function quit(message) {
    console.log(message);
    process.exit(0);
}
function fail(message) {
    console.error(message);
    process.exit(1);
}
api.connect().then(() => {
    console.log('Connected...');
    return api.preparePayment(address, payment, instructions).then(prepared => {
        console.log('Payment transaction prepared...');
        const {signedTransaction} = api.sign(prepared.txJSON, secret);
        console.log('Payment transaction signed...');
        api.submit(signedTransaction).then(quit, fail);
    });
}).catch(fail);
```

Currently, I am getting error I am passing designation address in array. But If i will as object then it will work fine. But I need to pass more than one address in single transaction.

Can you please give solution ASAP about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for now there is none... you can only use single destination address